# SQL count how many times email address OR phone number is entered

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server database that collects data from a brief contact form. It consists of the following columns:

```
ID, firstname, lastname, phone, email, comments
```

I need a query that returns all records along with how many times the phone number OR email address from that record has occurred in other records. In essence how many times a form has been submitted with either the same phone number or email address.

I've tried to join a query for all records and tried to tie it together with a second query with a case when condition on phone or email but I can't figure out how to tie the two together.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps the window functions will help here.  For example SELECT *,PhoneCnt = sum(1) over (partition by Phone) From YourTable

Answer (score 1):

partition can maybe help you here, for example

```
select t.id, t.firstname, t.lastname, t.phone, t.email,
       phones = count(*) over (partition by phone),
       emails = count(*) over (partition by email)
from   table1 t
```

See it at work [in this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n1jOzTdR)

From the comments I think you need to sum both counts and subtract 1 for the current row, somethint like this

```
select t.id, t.firstname, t.lastname, t.phone, t.email,
       counts = count(*) over (partition by phone) 
                + 
                count(*) over (partition by email) 
                - 1 /*subtract the current row*/
from   table1 t
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oBwie2q1)

Comment: Isn't `COUNT(*) OVER ...` a bit more idiomatic

Comment: @siggemannen you are right, I changed it

Comment: @siggemannen  sum(1) vs count(*) ... I see no difference other than I can save 2 key strokes (3 if you count the shift) :)

Comment: This reports on the occurrences by phone or by email separately. The idea is to report on whether the same email address OR phone number is used all at once. In your dbfiddle example it should return 2, 3, 2 for the respective records 1,2, 3 (record 1 has the same email as 2, record 2 has the same phone as 3 + same email as 1, record 3 has the same phone as 2).

Comment: @PDiddy It would be best and more clear if you provide us with sample data and expected output, my answer is based on my interpretation of the information you have in your original question. Please edit your answer and provide us with all relevant information

Comment: @JohnCappelletti good point! But think of extra time it takes to mentally parse SUM(1) vs COUNT(*) =)

Comment: @PDiddy I added another approach to my answer that reports the result as you described in your comment, if this is not what you mean than please edit your question and explain in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a subquery if performance isn't top-priority. Something like this

```
SELECT
    main.ID,
    main.firstname,
    main.lastname,
    main.phone,
    main.email,
    main.comments,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(0)
        FROM Table AS sub
        WHERE sub.phone = main.phone OR sub.email = main.email
    ) AS PhoneOrEmailOccurrences
FROM
    Table AS main
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately as you mentioned, it is very slow for a large amount of data